# Problem with curvature formula proof. Why this proof doesn't work?

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, derivatives, curvature

$$\kappa = \frac{||T'(t)||}{||r'(t)||}$$
$$T(t) = \frac{\frac{dr}{dt}}{||\frac{dr}{dt}||}$$
$$T'(t) = \frac{d}{dt} \frac{\frac{dr}{dt}}{||\frac{dr}{dt}||}$$
$$T'(t) = \frac{\frac{d^2r}{dt^2}}{||\frac{dr}{dt}||}$$
$$T'(t) = \frac{r''(t)}{||r'(t)||}$$
$$||T'|| = \frac{||r''(t)||}{||r'(t)||}$$
$$\kappa = \frac{||r''(t)||}{||r'(t)||^2}$$

Comment: as long as $\|r'(t)\|$ is not constant you can not calculate $T'$ the way you did. You have to use the quotient rule for derivatives.